# DAC controlled LED brightness

Tags: operational-amplifier, led, dac

I'm trying to control the brightness of 2 LED, with a 2-channel DAC.

My problem, is that even when the DAC outputs 0V, the LED lights up on the selected channel.
For 0V DAC output, I can measure 2.1 V across the LED.
I would like to have 0V on the opamp output, when the DAC outputs 0V.
[image]

Comment: Rather than rolling your own out of opamps and transistors my preference would be a constant current driver IC. They make ones with PWM signaling for current control or even direct digital control, so depending on the part you might not even need the DAC.

Comment: Is your circuit oscillating (oscilloscope required)? Perhaps a 100pF capacitor from opamp output to opamp minus_input will help. Also, be sure you have a bypass capacitor near the opamp power pins.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add some trim for the inevitable zero offsets in both the opamp and the DAC. Neither the opamp nor the DAC can truly swing down to 0V. So you'd need to inject some current around the LED to set the operating point such that the emitter of Q1/Q2 is slightly above 0V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwO8W2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 dumps about 200uA into R2 and moves the "LED off" point from 0.000V to 0.020V. That should hopefully be enough for the DAC to completely turn the LED off.

C1 stabilizes the op-amp at low LED currents. When Q1 is almost cut off, there is a fairly high impedance between the base and emitter of the transistor, and this destabilizes the op-amp and likely causes oscillation. C1 should fix that problem. Such oscillations can be insiduous since a lot will depend on luck in selecting the parts. You may well have op-amp+transistor pairs that won't oscillate at cut-off, while others will. With C1, this won't be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The typical output voltage of the DAC at '0' is 10mV which will cause about 100uA to flow, which is more than enough to visibly light a modern LED.

You can put a resistor across the LED to soak up  that current, perhaps 10K. Of course that will affect the linearity and temperature coefficient of the LED current a bit.

Linear control of current is not a great way to adjust visible LED brightness over a wide range because of the log response of the human eye. You might do better with PWM if you're mostly concerned about visible appearance.